# C# WindowsForms: Reproduce Microsoft control

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, controls

I would like to reproduce a `Control` in my WindowsFormsApplication that is equal to the refresh `Button` of the Windows Network connection form.

[image: Refresh button upper right]

Does anybody know which `Control` it is or how to build a equal one in C#? It seems to be a `PictureBox` but if you hover it with the `Cursor` it gets a semi transparent blue colored overlay.

Comment: you can change pictures on mouse overs :)

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks for the answer but I think it a .NET thing. It is the same when you hover a Button and it gets a blue colored overlay.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [XanderUI](https://github.com/Ricky310711/XanderUI) for this, add the button, change the button image and change both hover and click background colors to whatever color you like